# Selenium hover function doesn't work on a second call

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to hover my cursor to a tooltip and then check the text inside for a different products. But hover() function doesn't move cursor to the tooltip when it is called second time. How can I make it work on a subsequent calls also?

I've tried following:

```
final StringJoiner tooltipIconClassStringJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
tooltipIconClassStringJoiner.add(format(MULTI_CART_ENTRY_ID_FORMAT, productCode));
tooltipIconClassStringJoiner.add(MAINTENANCE_SECTION);
tooltipIconClassStringJoiner.add(TOOLTIP_ICON);

final SelenideElement element = $(tooltipIconClassStringJoiner.toString());
element.shouldBe(visible);
element.hover();

final StringJoiner maintenanceTooltipStringJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ");    
maintenanceTooltipStringJoiner.add(format(MULTI_CART_ENTRY_ID_FORMAT, productCode));
maintenanceTooltipStringJoiner.add(format(MAINTENANCE_TOOLTIP, productCode));

$(maintenanceTooltipStringJoiner.toString()).shouldBe(visible);
```

Also I've tried with actions:

```
new Actions(webDriverUtils.getDriver()).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

But both options worked only for the first call to hover/moveToElement function.

Comment: Can you try `Actions(webDriverUtils.getDriver()).moveToElement(element).build().perform();`

Comment: Doesn't work as well. I've also tried with ```release()``` call at the end

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java.

But I think you should get element again before hover() second time.

Use For Loop to wrap below code.

```
// get element that you want to hover first.
Actions(webDriverUtils.getDriver()).moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Comment: Actually I do. I have a feature file with steps for 3 different products.
So this code is executed once for each product